# OSError: [Errno 10048] only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

I have two different python scripts running on one computer. One uses socket to connect to another server on another computer on my network, the second acts as a websocket server for other clients to connect to. These two scripts will never connect to each other. When trying to run the second while the first is already running. I get

```
OSError: [Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address ('127.0.0.1', 6789): only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

This suggests that you can't have two different scripts on the same computer using sockets/websockets. Is this correct? Any work arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two scripts which are trying to be servers on *the same port*.

This isn't allowed, because when your computer receives a new connection on that port, how does it know which script gets the new connection?

If you have two servers they must use different port numbers.

Comment: One uses port 30003 and the other uses 6789. So I'm assuming this means that they aren't actually conflicting, just that the script using port 6789 is trying to start the server twice.

Comment: That's possible too. Or a completely different program is using port 6789 already.